# How do I disable add-ons in firefox when using selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I'm using Capybara selenium in my Rails project (on an Ubuntu 10.04 system) and I've just upgraded firefox now when I'm running my tests firefox loads but it now has all the add-ons installed and it waits until I set each one up for the first time.

Is there a way to disable all these add-ons when starting selenium?

OR

Is there a way to setup all my add-ons and save the settings so that it doesn't prompt me everytime the tests are ran?

**Update**

If I change it over to use chrome it works fine with that.

```
 Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
 end

 Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

I would like to do the tests with firefox though. I've setup a 'test' profile under firefox and tried using it with the following:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox_custom do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => "test")
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_firefox_custom
```

Which didn't work, it still tried to load my default profile.

I'm using the git version of capybara;

```
capybara (1.1.2)
  mime-types (>= 1.16)
  nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
  rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
  selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
  xpath (~> 0.1.4)
```

I've also tried using Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_firefox_custom

Comment: Is this due to auto-updates? This can be set in the Advanced tab under Update. If it's set up for first use, I would imagine you would only have to do it once? Or are you using a VM with an initial state? If not, I'm not sure! Sorry!

Comment: It's the setup of the plugins for first use. If I set them up though when selenium closes the browser all my settings are forgotten and I have to do this again.

Comment: You just want to disable the add-on compatibility check while starting  the browser?

Comment: No some of the plugins I use in firefox start up a wizard for first time use. This pops up everytime when running my tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a custom profile, and naming it however you like:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox_custom do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => "custom")
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_firefox_custom
```

Depending on the version you're using the API may have changed, but pretty much this is what you have to do.

Comment: When using javascript tests with 'js: true' it doesn't listen to this register_driver, is there a way around this?

Comment: Just use `javascript_driver` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't want to create a profile that you have to maintain (eg: checking in to source control, etc), you could create the profile on the fly as follows:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile["extensions.update.enabled"] = false
  profile["app.update.enabled"] = false
  profile["app.update.auto"] = false
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_firefox
```

That will create a profile on the fly that won't update the browser version or the extensions. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As I don't use Ubuntu I can only suggest my Windows workaround.
I think it's a proper way to use a second Firefox profile without Plug- ins to run selenium tests.

In Windows that can be achieved by feeding "firefox.exe -ProfileManager -no-remote" to Windows Run.

A untested way for Ubuntu would be [Alt]+[F2] and firefox -ProfileManager. 
It's important to close all Firefox Windows and maybe kill still existing processes before

Comment: Ok, I've made a 'test' profile in firefox and disabled all my add-ons. How do I tell my rails plugin for selenium to use the 'test' profile for Firefox?