# Is it possible to disable Firefox plugins from Selenium code

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable add-ons in firefox when using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578108/how-do-i-disable-add-ons-in-firefox-when-using-selenium)

I would like  know how to ,if there is a way, disable some or all Firefox plugins before or during the tests using the RemoteWebdriver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Harald while they seems similar they are using Webdriver locally and I specifically asking if there is a way to do it with a RemoteWebdriver, I spent 3 full days looking for a way to do this with no success.

Comment: they mention the use of a custom firefox profile as a solution, as does [Selenium Remote Webdriver documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#using-a-firefoxprofile) so I figured this to be a duplicate, sorry. [FirefoxProfile](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html) would allow you to clean any extensioncaches as well, so that might be your friend.

Comment: The most reliable solution is to create a profile with those plugins & extensions removed/disabled, and force Selenium to use that particular profile.

Answer (score -1):

Try this piece of code,

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AddExtension("location xpi of plugin");
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("firefox_profile", profile);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

I hope it works

Comment: He is asking if an extension can be removed, not added.

Comment: He said "disable some or all Firefox plugins". So if you want some enabled you have to add them like this.